# Angular 9 share HTML between components

Tags: angular

I'm developing an application with Angular 9.

I'm trying to understand what is the best way to share HTML between components.

for instance I have the below SVG code which I want to include in other components as well. (**Note** that i have many more SVGs that i would like to use in different places in the components)

In AngularJS i could have done it with directives. But in Angular 9 i don't see that the directive as an HTML part.

What is the best practice i should use?

```
<div class="icon" tooltip="{{dic.MESSAGES.gameViewed}}">
    <svg version="1.1" class="eyeIcon" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
         x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 511.999 511.999" style="enable-background:new 0 0 511.999 511.999;"
         xml:space="preserve" height="15pt" width="15pt">

      <path d="M508.745,246.041c-4.574-6.257-113.557-153.206-252.748-153.206S7.818,239.784,3.249,246.035
      c-4.332,5.936-4.332,13.987,0,19.923c4.569,6.257,113.557,153.206,252.748,153.206s248.174-146.95,252.748-153.201
      C513.083,260.028,513.083,251.971,508.745,246.041z M255.997,385.406c-102.529,0-191.33-97.533-217.617-129.418
      c26.253-31.913,114.868-129.395,217.617-129.395c102.524,0,191.319,97.516,217.617,129.418
      C447.361,287.923,358.746,385.406,255.997,385.406z" />

        <path d="M255.997,154.725c-55.842,0-101.275,45.433-101.275,101.275s45.433,101.275,101.275,101.275
      s101.275-45.433,101.275-101.275S311.839,154.725,255.997,154.725z M255.997,323.516c-37.23,0-67.516-30.287-67.516-67.516
      s30.287-67.516,67.516-67.516s67.516,30.287,67.516,67.516S293.227,323.516,255.997,323.516z" />
    </svg>
    <div class="iconData">
        {{gameInfo.counter}}
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You could wrap that markup in a component, to make it reusable.

Comment: @ConnorsFan I have many small SVGs, so i do not want to create many components for each one

Comment: It's not just svgs.. You are using divs too!So you have to create components if you want to be resuable!

Comment: Components are just directives with template. Why don’t you show what you would’ve done in AngularJS and I can show you how to migrate it

Comment: @Tzimpo correct i have `divs`.
Is there a way to share HTML data as done in AngularJS directives? (or somthing similart)

Comment: after thinking about it again, i can do it with a component to which i will pass with SVG to show